# Maximum overlapping of arithmetic sequences with intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, sequence, intervals

I have n number of arithmetic sequences with intervals. I need to find the first point at which most of this intervals overlap. The sequences are infinite. Let me give an example for finite sequences where I have total 8 sequences.
Given,

N=8. So, there are 8 sequences. The sequences are as follows:

seq-1: [{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}..{17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24}]

seq-2: [{9,10,11,12,**13**,14,15,16}..{25,26,27,28,**29**,30,31,32}]

seq-3: [{1,2,3,4}..{9,10,11,12}..{17,18,19,20}..{25,26,27,28}]

seq-4: [{5,6,7,8}..{**13**,14,15,16}..{21,22,23,24}..{**29**,30,31,32}]

seq-5: [{5}..{**13**}..{21}..{**29**}]

seq-6: [{4}..{8}..{12}..{16}..{20}..{24}..{28}..{32}]

seq-7: [{9,11,**13**,15}..{25,27,**29**,31}]

seq-8: [{2}..{18}]

Here point 13 and 29 have the maximum overlap with 4 over laps. And the first point is 13.

Can I solve it using some efficient algorithm like O(n),O(n^2), O(n^3), O(n^4), O(n log n) etc.
Here, the value of n is 8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And almost any question beginning like "can I do ..." can be answered with "yes". Please try to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest applying Distribution Counting algorithm.

Below is a simple demo for the algorithm with 3 sample sequences:

```
seq-1: [{1,2,}..{9,10}]

seq-2: [{1,2,3}..{5,7,8}]

seq-3: [{2,3,4}..{6,7}..{9,10}]
```

You need to find the maximum value in all sequences. Which is 10 in this case.

Create an int array of 11 elements starting from 0 to 10.

```
i   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
--------------------------------------------------
A[i]| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |
```

Now we count the appearance of elements in all sequences by increasing its value by 1.

seq-1: [{1,2,}..{9,10}]

```
This sequence contains 1, 2, 9, and 10.
Increase value at index 1, 2, 9, and 10 by 1.

i   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
--------------------------------------------------
A[i]| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  1 |
```

seq-2: [{1,2,3}..{5,7,8}]

```
This sequence contains 1, 2, 3, 5, 7,and 8.
Increase value at index 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, and 8 by 1.

i   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
--------------------------------------------------
A[i]| 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  1 |
```

seq-3: [{2,3,4}..{6,7}..{9,10}]

```
This sequence contains 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, and 10.
Increase value at index 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, and 10 by 1.

i   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
--------------------------------------------------
A[i]| 0 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |  2 |
```

In the end, it is obvious that number 2 has the maximum overlapping times of 3 between all the sequences.

Hope my suggestion will help!